# What is it to be defined

Tags: calculus

The book says " Notice that for limit of f(x)/g(x) as x approaches to a, to make sense f(x)/g(x) must be defined for x close to a but not equal to a."

What it means with saying that it must be defined?

Comment: For example, $\log(x)$ is not defined for $x \le 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the domain of the function $\frac fg$ must have points arbitrarily close to (but distinct from) $a$.

Comment: Otherwise, the limit will make sense. It will be undefined. Am I correct to thinking that not making sense means ,in this case, being undefined?

Comment: Actually, it is the opposite: without that restriction, **every** number will be a limit of that function. Check for yourself that, for instance,$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0):\lvert x-(-1)\rvert<\delta\implies\left\lvert\sqrt x-\pi\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$Yes, $\lim_{x\to-1}\sqrt x=\pi$ (and it is equalt to **any** other number, too).

Comment: When I choose an x value in -2<x<1 square root of x become sth that I don't know. In this case, how I can say that |(square root of x) + pi | < epsilon.

Comment: Take any $\varepsilon>0$. Now, take $\delta=1$. Then$$\lvert x-(-1)\rvert<\delta\implies\left\lvert\sqrt x-\pi\right\rvert<1$$because no $x$ in $((-1)-1,(-1)+1)(=(-2,0))$ belongs to the domain of the square root function. It is vacuously true!

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is defined at the point $x=a$ if $f(a)$ exists. For example, if $f(x)=\frac 1x$, then $f(0)=\frac 10$ which doesn't exist (and is therefore called "undefined"). What this book is suggesting is that this $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ may not be defined for $x=0$, but has to be for values very slightly larger or smaller than $0$

Answer (score 0):

It means that if $f(x)/g(x)$ is undefined for a lot of values of $x$ near $a$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)/g(x)$ might not make any sense.

Remember, there is a "for every" in the definition of a limit.